# Hibernate: Native query can't process value wrapped in single quotes

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.4 and Postgres 10.

In my database I have defined an enum type called `model_type` and registered Hibernate with the corresponding `UserType`.

I'm trying to perform the following query but keep getting exception because of the single-quotes format I use.

```
session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM template WHERE game_model='?1'")//
   .addEntity(Template.class) //
   .setParameter(1, GameModel.SINGLE)
   .getResultList();
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of []
```

I have tried many options, like:
`..game_model=':model'` and `.setParameter("model", GameModel.SINGLE)`

The only thing that makes this work is if I prepare the string using `String.format` with `'%s'`

Any idea how to still make this work?

Comment: Please also include the stack-trace for the exception.

Comment: Updated the question with the exception

Comment: Looks like `GameModel.SINGLE` is enum. Try removing `''` from query like `FROM Template WHERE m_gameModel=?1`

Comment: I had a mistake in the query I initially put in the question - but now it's fixed to reflect what I really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Removing the `''` would result in an exception something like  `can't cast game_model=bytea` - Hibernate having casting issues